# Como fazer download do conteudo blob no php

Tags: php

Tenho arquivos xml armazenados em um campo blob de uma tabela mysql, gostaria de saber como faço para baixar esses arquivos no disco local do usuário de forma automatica utilizando o php.

Crie uma função porem baixa no servidor e não no disco local.

```
function baixarArquivos($res) {
    while ($arq = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {       
        $nomearquivo = $arq['CHAVEXML'];
        $arquivoxml  = $arq['XML'];        
        
        $path = 'c:\Temp\\xml\\'.$nomearquivo.'xml';
        file_put_contents($path, $arquivoxml);      
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Você não pode fazer isso no computador do usuário.
O que tem que fazer é fornecer o download do arquivo.
Exemplo:

```
<?php
    $path = 'c:\Temp\\xml\\'.$nomearquivo.'xml';
    $nomearquivo = 'seu_arquivo.xml';
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$novoNome.'"');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0');
    // Envia o arquivo para o cliente
    readfile($path);
```

Comment: Entendi amigo, eu preciso na verdade baixar tudo de uma vez, deixar bem simples pro usuário final. Um botão que o usuário aperta e o sistema faz o resto. Eu tenho isso no delphi, precisava ter o mesmo em php ou em alguma outra linguagem que rode com apache no linux.

Comment: while not dtmConexao.fdqXmlPdv.eof  do
begin       dtmConexao.fdqXmlPdvXML.SaveToFile('c:\teste\xml\'+dtmConexao.fdqXmlPdvCHAVEXML.AsString+'.xml');
      dtmConexao.fdqXmlPdv.Next;
  end;

Comment: PHP é executado do lado do servidor. Você não tem acesso a máquina cliente. Seu site pode criar um arquivo zip com vários arquivos e disponibilizar como download. Mas sempre o usuário do seu site vai precisar fazer o download.